# Getting message in ibmmq Node.js

Tags: node.js, jmeter, jms, ibm-mq

I'm using ibmmq module https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs

I need to get an xml message from a queue and than make an xsl-transformation.
I put messages to the queue with JMeter and if I browse messages in rfhutil I can see them as is on the Data tab.
But when I get it in the code

```
 function getCB(err, hObj, gmo,md,buf, hConn ) {
   // If there is an error, prepare to exit by setting the ok flag to false.
   if (err) {...
   } else {
     if (md.Format=="MQSTR") {
       console.log("message <%s>", decoder.write(buf));
     } else {
       console.log("binary message: " + buf);
     }
  }
```

I get my message with some service information:

buf=`RFH �"�MQSTR   � <mcd><Msd>jms_text</Msd></mcd>  X<jms><Dst>queue://MY_QM/MY_QUEUE</Dst><Tms>1657791724648</Tms><Dlv>2</Dlv></jms> ...My_message...`

How can I get only My message like I do in rfhutil?
I can get it with string methods, but it looks like crutches.

Comment: Try adding MQGMO_NO_PROPERTIES to your gmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message has the headers created by a JMS application. There are various ways of dealing with it. You can

- Have the sending app disable sending that structure (setting the [targClient](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=mjmomm-exchanging-messages-between-jms-application-traditional-mq-application) property)
- Use GMO options to ignore the properties (MQGMO_NO_PROPERTIES)
- Have your application deal with the RFH2 stucture. See for example the amqsget.js sample in the Node.js repo which includes this fragment:

```
    switch (format) {
      case MQC.MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2:
        hdr   = mq.MQRFH2.getHeader(buf);
```